# Array push only works when array is predefined with value

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking to create an array that keeps growing with one random number every time the PHP scripts runs. If I secure that the `[$_SESSION["my_array"]` has a value predefined then it works with increase per each script round.

However, if I do not pre-define the above mentioned array, then a random number is being created but the array does not grow in amount of stored digits.

**Question:** Is there a way of avoiding the need of populating the array at start? I would like the array to start with being empty.

```html
<pre>

    <a href="session_destroy.php">Destroy session</a>

    <?php
        session_start();

        $_SESSION["my_array"] ?? [];
        $my_array = $_SESSION["my_array"];

        $new_random_value = rand(1, 6);

        array_push($my_array, $new_random_value);

        $_SESSION["my_array"] = $my_array;


        var_dump($my_array);

        var_dump($_SESSION);

    ?>
```

**My [destroy_session] file:**

```html
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: I don't know what your'e asking but you can't have any output/html before your `session_start`

Comment: Try to assign session's array with `$_SESSION["my_array"] = $_SESSION["my_array"] ?? [];`

Comment: This code does nothing: `$_SESSION["my_array"] ?? [];`

Comment: @CristianoCasciotti Your suggestion solves my issues. If you could please move your comment into an answer and add a line explaining why your suggestion works, I will go ahead and approve the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing the session array, you have to initialize it like this:

`$_SESSION["my_array"] = $_SESSION["my_array"] ?? [];`

Otherwise you don't have a start value in your array, and that's the reason why your push doesn't grow the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $my_array = $_SESSION["my_array"];
    if(!is_array($my_array)) {
        $my_array = array();
    }

    $new_random_value = rand(1, 6);
    array_push($my_array, $new_random_value);
    $_SESSION["my_array"] = $my_array;

    var_dump($my_array);
    var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
```